# Update function in content provider not updating database

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am struggling to get the update method working in my content provider, the update returns 0 and there is no updated information in the table. The table is populated at this point.

Here's the update function:

```
   @Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = leagueDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {
        case LEAGUES:
            rowsUpdated = db.update(LeagueContract.LEAGUE_TABLE_NAME,
                    values, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case LEAGUE_ID:
            String newSelection = appendToSelection(uri, selection);
            rowsUpdated = db.update(LeagueContract.LEAGUE_TABLE_NAME,
                    values, newSelection, selectionArgs);

            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised uri: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    return rowsUpdated;

}

private String appendToSelection(Uri uri, String selection) {
    String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    StringBuilder newSelection = new StringBuilder(LeagueContract.COLUMN_KEY_ID + "=" + id);
    if (selection != null && !selection.isEmpty()) {
        newSelection.append(" AND " + selection);
    }
    return newSelection.toString();
}
```

Here's where I call the update of the content provider:

```
     message = "Player 1 wins";// we should get the name
     ContentValues mUpdateValues = new ContentValues();
     String[] projectionFields = new String[] {
     LeagueContract.COLUMN_NAME_SCORE   };
     Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(LeagueContentProvider.LEAGUE_URI, player1Id);
     ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();
     Cursor  cursor = content.query(uri, projectionFields, null, null, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     int score = cursor.getInt(0);
     score ++;
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(LeagueContract.COLUMN_NAME_SCORE,score);
     content.update(uri,values,null,null);
```

Comment: Everything looks fine for me. Did you check player id?

Comment: Yes, it pulls the score from the dataebase fine. So player1Id is correct. I thought it all looked fine, really cannot see the issue!

Comment: Problem solved, COLUMN_KEY_ID was an integer, the title of the column was used and this then worked.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your DB with [the remote shell](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html) and try to update manually.

Also you can add log messages in your content provider to trace values.